# Pandas Columns to Dict Preserving Order

Tags: python-3.x, sorting, pandas, dictionary

Given the following data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['a','c','b'],
                   'b':['foo','bar','baz']})
df
    a   b
0   a   foo
1   c   bar
2   b   baz
```

When I create a dict from the columns, I get this:

```
dict(zip(df.a,df.b))
{'a': 'foo', 'b': 'baz', 'c': 'bar'}
```

You'll notice that it sorts the key column (a) automatically.

My question is: How do I avoid this?

I'd like a dict that looks like this:

```
{'a': 'foo', 'c': 'bar', 'b': 'baz', }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: but the key dict order is not necessarily the insertion order this has nothing to do with pandas, you'd have to use a orderedDict if you want to preserve the insertion order

Comment: You cannot control the order of keys in a dictionary.

Comment: OrderedDict worked! Thanks, EdChum. If  you want to post it as an answer, I'll mark accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to control the order of keys in a Python dictionary. The standard library contains a different data structure for this - [`OrderedDict`](https://pymotw.com/2/collections/ordereddict.html) - which remembers the order in which keys were added.

In this case, you can populate it via

```
In [39]: OrderedDict(df.to_records(index=False))
Out[39]: OrderedDict([('a', 'foo'), ('c', 'bar'), ('b', 'baz')])
```